# Get cells in Excel to merge with cells in different rows using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, merge

I'm trying to create a dataframe using Pandas but I'm having issues because of the structure of the dataset.

My dataset's headers are split in two different rows. My issue is trying to merge those rows together, having each cell merge with the cell underneath it.

This is an example of what my dataset looks like -

```
Client 1     | Client 2
------------ | ------------
Grand Total  | Grand Total
------------ | ------------
$50          | $100
```

What I'm trying to do -

```
Client 1 Grand Total | Client 2 Grand Total
-------------------- | --------------------
$50                  | $100
```

Everything I found online talks about merging data in multiple rows to a single row but not about merging the cells in different rows.

How do I get cells to merge with other cells in different rows? I'm obviously looking for a solution where I don't edit the actual dataset. More so, a solution where I don't have to hardcode headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create `columns` from `MultiIndex`. If all values are strings, simpliest is `map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('Client 1', 'Grand Total'): {0: '$50'}, 
                   ('Client 2', 'Grand Total'): {0: '$100'}})

print (df)
     Client 1    Client 2
  Grand Total Grand Total
0         $50        $100

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Client 1', 'Client 2'], ['Grand Total']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])

df.columns = df.columns.map(' '.join)

print (df)
  Client 1 Grand Total Client 2 Grand Total
0                  $50                 $100


print (df.columns.tolist())
['Client 1 Grand Total', 'Client 2 Grand Total']
```

Comment: I should've probably mentioned that there are over 100 columns. Is there a different way of doing it without having to input a 100 column names into my script?

Comment: 100 columns is no problem. It is very small data for pandas ;) But in my solution is not necessary know names, if `MultiIndex`. Or solution does not work?

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: I'm using "map" because all my values are strings. I assume I have to put in the values like so - df.columns = df.columns.map('<Client 1 Grand Total> '.join)

Comment: It means you overwrite `df` by `orderdict`. Try check my solution, need join by space only - is simple join upper value with lower for each pair.